# Why would I choose UTF-8 over ISO 8859-1 as the content encoding for my site?

Tags: content-encoding

Assume that the site is still in it's design phases so there's no initial work to pick one over the other from the start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) you have increased flexibility over [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). The former can encode any character included in Unicode while the latter is limited to Western European languages.

ISO 8859-1 ("Latin1") doesn't include, for example, Greek, Hebrew, Arabic, Cyrillic, Chinese, Japanese and Korean, etc.

Comment: Is the LS (line separator) character also supported in HTML or do I still have to use the classic \r\n kludge?

Comment: @Evan: normally you just use `\n`.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat I thought \n was specific to *nix platforms whereas \r is specific to Windows. Don't you need a combination of the two to make the code platform independent?

Comment: @Evan: I create content in both Windows and Linux which is hosted by both IIS and Apache in all combinations of edit/host and I never pay any attention to the line endings (which are independent of the encoding, by the way). I think (unfortunately?) that `\r\n` has graduated from kludge to a de facto standard. (It's actually more "typewriter-like" than Unix line endings.)

Comment: Decent Windows text editors can use `\n` or `\r\n`.

Comment: @Evan: `\n` is Linux/Unix, `\r` is Mac, `\r\n` is Windows. But you can use any of those for any platform's server as far as I know. I've never had any problems on Windows using  just `\n`.

Comment: In fact, when dealing with HTML, `\n`, `\r\n`, `\r` and similar characters are all being displayed as a one single whitespace character, unless typed inside <pre> or viewing the page source…